# Change the back colour of answerd question button in android

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, button

Hi all  ok i am doin a online exam with android for my semester......suppose i have 10 questions and only 1 question is displayed one at a time....and 10 buttons with ID as button1,button2,button3.......with the click of each button it will jump directly to the corresponding question......for eg if i click button 5 it will display question 5  and so on........whenever a question is answered its button backcolor should change to red..indicating that it is answered.....eg i answer question5 then button5.backcolor =drawing.color.red...

in short how do i change the backcolor of all the buttons using a loop???...
In this i have my buttons in a fragment and i show my result in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

In my suggeston, make a variable called answered, intialize it to zero and make it one when user answers the question.
When user answers the question change the color button by following code-

```
int answered = 0; // change the value of answered = 1, when user answers

if(answered == 1){
button1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.pasta_co)); 
// for api level 23 and above  
                             
button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pasta_color)); 
// for api level below 23

}


button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
        
            showQuestion(yourQuestionNumber);// function to display your 
question
           
    }
});
```

getResources().getColor() - It is deprecated for api level 23 and above, that is you can use it but it is no more reccomended by google to use that function.

ContextCompat.getColor() - You can use this function in order to change background color of button if u have api 23 and above, it takes two parameters
first one is Context and second parameter is color which you want to put as background for button.

button1.setOnClickListener.... method - this method will be called when you click the button, so when you click the button you can display your desired question.